# How to trim a string which changes at each result

Tags: sql, excel, openedge, progress-db, ms-query

I have data which contains a date and a batch number. I need to be able to trim down the batch number removing the leading word "Job " from each. The issue i have is each result is different and is of a different length also.

To try and deal with this i have tried to use `LEFT` and `CHARINDEX` to trim it but get a syntax error back. Because i am using MS Query on a open edge v10 progress odbc database it is not clear as to what the issue is. Below is the code i have produced.

```
    SELECT 

      Delivery_0.DelProposedDate
    , Delivery_0.DelBatchNumber
    , LEFT(Delivery_0.DelBatchNumber,CHARINDEX(' ',Delivery_0.DelBatchNumber)-1) as 'JobID'

FROM SBS.PUB.Delivery Delivery_0
```

Currently the data looks like this:

```
DelProposedDate               DelBatchNumber
05/05/2017                    Job 321924
08/02/2019                    Job 356812/4
29/03/2017                    Job 328585
```

I am trying to get it to look like this:

```
DelProposedDate               DelBatchNumber             JobID
05/05/2017                     Job 321924                321924
08/02/2019                     Job 356812/4              356812/4
29/03/2017                     Job 328585                328585
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to exclude the left-most 4 characters ('Job '). This is the same a showing the right-most x characters where x = length-of-string - 4. I'm not that conversant with Progress' variant of SQL, but something like:

```
Right(DelBatchNumber, Len(DelBatchNumber) - 4)
```

would do it. You may need to substitute the Progress equivalent of Right and Len, and possibly check the order of the parameters Right takes.

Comment: Thank you this worked as expected. The progress equivalent is: 

Right(DelBatchNumber, Length(DelBatchNumber) - 4)

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server has a function that explicitly does this, [`STUFF()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
select stuff(Delivery_0.DelBatchNumber, 1, 4, '')
```

This replaces the first four characters with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select replace ('Job 321924','Job ','')
```

output

```
'321924'
```

first parameter is the string you want to change,
second parameter is the string you want to replace,
third parameter is the string you want to replace with.

So here i simply replaced 'Job ' by an empty string

Note that it returns a string and not an integer, you might need to use CONVERT/CAST if you want the result as integer

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, which tries to replace the 'Job ' string with empty string:

```
 SELECT 
      Delivery_0.DelProposedDate
    , Delivery_0.DelBatchNumber
    , REPLACE(Delivery_0.DelBatchNumber,'Job ','')  as 'JobID'
FROM SBS.PUB.Delivery Delivery_0
```